# PWA in WkWebview and Google Sign via SFSafariViewController (no redirect to wkwebview)

Tags: ios, google-oauth, progressive-web-apps, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I try to package a pwa app with Google Sign In wkwebview for ios14.
Pwa works well but Google Signin fails.

In the first page, I am trying to do goole authentication via sfsafariviewcontroller. the problem is that i am never redirected to the wkwebview after authenticating.

I read lot of things about this subject but i'm completely lost.

Actually, i put this link on my google sign in button in my pwa.

```
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=com.googleusercontent.apps.[client_id]:/oauth&response_type=code&scope=profile%20email&prompt=select_account
```

- I have declared the google urls schemes in xcode
- I put this on ViewController
  `let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: navigationAction.request.url!) safariVC.delegate = self present(safariVC, animated: true)`
- I put this function in Scenedelegate and i catch well the url callback
  `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {print(URLContexts)}`
- I put this function in AppDelegate but it never call
  `func application( _ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool { return true}`

It has been 3 days since reading the forum looking for an answer without success.
Can anyone help?
Many thanks in advance.
Mat

Comment: So... did you manage to solve it?